# Wordpress/woocommerce css error

Tags: wordpress

I've followed: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67247/how-to-display-product-specific-to-a-category-with-woocommerce-plugin

This code is placed in CustomPageT1, and has this code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content container">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <ul class="products">
                <?php
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'product_cat' => 'skydd-mot-djur', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                            <li class="post-18 product type-product status-publish product_cat-skydd-mot-manniskor first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="width: 25%;float:left">    

                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">

                                    <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" height="300px" />'; ?>

                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                    <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                                </a>

                                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                            </li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul><!--/.products-->

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This page is created by adding `/* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */` and then add it from the "add page" function. Then copy-paste from page.php into this file.

I can edit and all, the logo, menu, and some design works great. Without the Woocommerce one, in style.css I can get the css. But from the theme it doesnt fetch the css.

Which means that it looks bad, without the css.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have created a page without a link to the header file.
By creating a page with this code

```
/* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */
```

means create a page with template `CustomPageT1`. 
The new page has no means to connect to the CSS file.
create the `header-CustomPageT1.php` file with the link to the CSS file andd upload to it's corresponding theme folder.
Also change this code: `get_header()` to `get_header(CustomPageT1)`

Comment: Will I need to create a new theme folder?

Comment: Take a look at this page, it is about child themes https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes